# On limits related to $\frac1{\ln n}\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n^4}\frac1r$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

> $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\ln n}\sum_{r=1}^{n^4}\frac1r,\qquad M=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lfloor\frac1{\ln n}\sum_{r=1}^{n^4}\frac1r\right\rfloor$$

---

I know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^{n^4}\frac nr=\int_{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}1/n}^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^4/n}\frac{dx}x=\ln 4-\color{red}{\ln 0}\to-\infty$$

I suspect the limits to both doesn't exist.

Comment: you may use the fact that $\sum\limits_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r}\sim \ln n$.

Comment: Your integral argument is close to correct.  You are in too much of a hurry to take limits; $\int_{1/n}^{n^3} \frac{dx}{x} = \ln(n^3) - \ln(1/n) = 4\ln n$.  If you divide by $\ln n$ and take the limit, you most certainly don't get infinity.

Comment: @Slade thanks that's a good trick

Comment: @Aditya It's tricky to make it rigorous (or I should say that it's easy to _forget_ to make it rigorous), because there are two limits involved, but it definitely works if you're careful with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exercise is meant to help you discover/apply the properties of the partial sums of the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), known as the harmonic numbers $$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k.$$ For example, for every $n\geqslant2$, $$\log n\lt H_n\lt1+\log n.$$ This suffices to answer your question. Do you see why?

Note that, if $\lfloor\ \rfloor$ in the formula for $M$ stands for the integer part, the bounds above yield $$M=4.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the result

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}.....+\frac{1}{n}  - \ln(n) = \gamma $$

This gives, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{4\ln(n)+\gamma}{\ln(n)} = 4$$

Comment: $\gamma$=EulerMasasa?

Comment: Euler–Mascheroni -_-

Comment: Is this answering the question? Anyway, the first identity is wrong: $1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n-\log n$ is never equal to $\gamma$.

Comment: @Did I didn't knew that he posted wrong identity, can you elaborate on this either on comments or on your answer as an edit?

Comment: wait @Did from a reliable source "The difference between the nth harmonic number and the natural logarithm of n converges to the Euler–Mascheroni constant."

Comment: Of course, and no need for your reliable source to know that. But you see, it happens that "equal to" and "converges to" are two different notions. In the present case, the LHS *converges to* $\gamma$ but, as I mentioned, it is never equal to $\gamma$.

Comment: @did , i meant that only.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n^4} \frac{1}{r} \sim \log (n^4) = 4 \log n$$

then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sum_{r=1}^{n^4} \frac{1}{r}/\log n\right)= 4$$

Comment: see my edit....

Comment: @Aditya: I see your edit. So?

Comment: I meant the $\ln 0$ term

Comment: @Aditya: the accepted answer (and Did's and mine) don't address $\log 0$ at all. I think Did's is most responsive to your question and only posted mine since I had taken the trouble to do it.

Comment: Oh but i wished simplicity here.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt this conversation but what is not *simple* here? Simple $\ne$ wrong. For example, @daniel's argument is simple and true.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> $\tt\mbox{This is straightforward with Stoltz-Cesàro Theorem}$:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{\ds{\sum_{r\ =\ 1}^{n^{4}}}1/r \over \ln\pars{n}}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{H_{n^{4}} \over \ln\pars{n}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{\Psi\pars{n^{4} + 1} + \gamma \over \ln\pars{n}}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}
{\Psi\pars{\bracks{n + 1}^{4} + 1} - \Psi\pars{n^{4} + 1}\over
\ln\pars{n + 1} - \ln\pars{n}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}n\braces{%
\Psi\pars{\bracks{n + 1}^{4} + 1} - \Psi\pars{n^{4} + 1}}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}n\braces{%
\ln\pars{\bracks{n + 1}^{4} + 1} - \ln\pars{n^{4} + 1}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}n\ln\pars{\bracks{n + 1}^{4} + 1 \over n^{4} + 1}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}n
\ln\pars{1 + {4n^{3} + 6n^{2} + 4n  \over n^{4} + 1}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}n
\ln\pars{1 + {4  \over n}}=\color{#66f}{\Large 4}
\end{align}

Comment: This, although correct, doesn't clear out any misunderstanding in the original post, and is hardly enlightening, in my opinion.